# header('Content-Type: image/jpeg') makes black site

Tags: php, thumbnails

I have a code to do thumbs like this:

```
 switch (strtolower($imgOrginalsize['mime'])) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                $new = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
                imagecopyresampled($new, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $imgOrginalsize[0], $imgOrginalsize[1]);
                header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); // when I comment this everything works good, but with this I have a whole black site. What is wrong? In png it doesn't destroy my site.
                imagepng($new, $pathToSave . $file_name, 9);
                imagedestroy($new);
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                $img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                $new = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
                imagecopyresampled($new, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $imgOrginalsize[0], $imgOrginalsize[1]);
                header('Content-Type: image/png');
                imagepng($new, $pathToSave . $file_name, 9);
                imagedestroy($new);
                break;
            default:
                die();
        }
```

Whole site is black when I add to my code header jpeg. In png It doesn't destroy it and everything works good. I cannot see where is my mistake. And site looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You need to stop _lying_ to the browser ;-) … you tell it you are sending a JPEG image, but what function are you using afterwards to output the image data …?

Comment: *"when I comment this everything works good"* – Define "good". What *does* it show then?

Comment: @misorude The way you worded your comment brings me great joy.

Comment: This is my whole code to create thumb. I still don't know what to do with this ;p

Comment: check my answer

Comment: You use `imagepng()` and pretend its a `jpg` So what do you expect

Comment: Reeally guys thanks... to much time at computer and I didn't see this mistake :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty obvious. Look carefully at both these lines ;-)

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagepng($new, $pathToSave . $file_name, 9);
```

Change it to the correct content type! Use `imagejpeg()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: Ohhhhh GOD!!!! I'm really sorry for this simple mistake!!! Ohhhh My.... Thanks ;p

Comment: Haha, no worries, can you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Ofcourse :) I have to wait to mark it 6 minutes :)

Comment: Note that this code does *not output an image to stdout*! It's a mystery where the image data you're sending to the browser actually comes from.